# problem in installing amd driver radeon hd 5460

Tags: 12.04, drivers, radeon, amd-graphics, fglrx

I tried to install my gpu in Ubuntu 12.04 with this link

[What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/126513#126513)

but when I type this command line:

> $sudo aticonfig --initial

I got this err:

> aticonfig: No supported adapters detected

what should I must to do?
any suggestion about this?

I use Ubuntu 12.04 and hp pavilion dm4-1060ea note book and ati radeon hd5460

I used this command to find out the model of my gpu card:

$lspci | grep VGA

and showed me these:

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor
>   Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
>
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee
>   ATI Manhattan [Mobility Radeon HD 5400 Series]

Thanks

Hamid

Comment: HD5460 should be detected and supported in Catalyst. If it is not, then this is a bug that should be reported to ATI.

Answer (score 1):

I tried several times to do this for my wifes computer, with little success and eventually gave up!

Looking at the AMD site for the current driver, released 5/22, there are many packages that you should ensure are installed on your system to make this work:

```
gimp-help-en
gimp-help-common
XFree86-Mesa-libGL
libstdc++
libgcc
XFree86-libs
fontconfig
freetype
zlib
gcc
Xorg/Xserver 7.4 and above (up to 1.14)
Linux kernel 2.6 or above (up to 3.11)
glibc version 2.2 or 2.3
POSIX Shared Memory (/dev/shm) support is required for 3D applications
```

Most of these should be on your system already, but you should check.

Read through the driver preliminary documentation at http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDCatalyst14-4LINReleaseNotes.aspx, and perhaps consider downloading the latest version of the drivers at [http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86#amd-catalyst-packages](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86#amd-catalyst-packages).